# two algorithms, same results on my machine, different results on tests

Tags: go, sum, binary-search

I am new in code, so, it would be cool,if somebody would helo me.
Task: 
You have target-numer and a lot of other numbers. You need to find the numbers that you add up to get a sum equal to the target-number. If you found this numbers, you type "1" in out-put file, otherwise type "0". All numbers are in diapason 0 < N < 999 999 999
input-file format:
5
1 8 9 2 4 1 5 3....

I wrote 2 different algorithms, both work correctly. But I have tests,(no code sources, they are on the website, where I found task) and first algorithm passes all test accept of speed-test, but second can't pass even 1st test, have error "wrong answer". 
I want to test my fastest version. 
This algorithm does:

1. Open the file with numbers.
2. Convert all strings with numbers to numbers. Write all the numbers in a slice.
3. Write the target from the array to a separate variable. Target = the first element of the slice due to the input format.
4. Create a new slice. Rewrite it with all the numbers that < = target.
5. Sort the slice in ascending order (built-in sorting from golang)
6. Find the sum:
   6.1 take the current slice element and subtract it from the target. The resulting number = the second term.
   6.2 using the binary array dissection Method, we search for this number in the slice. (method from golanfg package)
   6.3 If found, write 1 to the output file and exit the program.
   6.4 Otherwise go to a new iteration of the loop and return to point 6.1
   6.5 If the cycle has ended and we haven't left the program, we assume that there are no 2 numbers forming the sum for the target. print 0 to the output file.

Could you help me to find, where is mistake? 
Here is the link for the file on my git:
https://github.com/0xBECEDA/ozon-tasks/blob/master/task-f/SO1.go
This file will create test-file with numbers:
https://github.com/0xBECEDA/ozon-tasks/blob/master/task-f/make-test-file.go
This is test-file:
https://github.com/0xBECEDA/ozon-tasks/blob/master/task-f/input.txt

Comment: Please show code within the question, not as links. Ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is also not enough information to help debug this.

Answer (score 1):

first your problem, you read input from file to only 100 byte slice, but your input data can consume more place `All numbers are in diapason 0 < N < 999 999 999` ,so i think you don`t read all the data from file

Comment: it is only 1 portion of read data, I have a loop and every time read 100 bytes till the end of file.

Comment: @SofiaS. check getNumbersFromFile func, i cant understand what you do in else block especially this statement `curNum =  int(curN) + (curNum * 10)` and why you iterate byte slice i think number can consume more than one byte )) your getNumbersFromFile func hard to read , simlify to smth like this one : `for i, digit := range strings.Split(string(slice), " ") {  num ,_ := strconv.Atoi(digit); numsSlice[i] = num}` :)